# How to resize image by scale Tensorflow image

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code produces an error. I understand that `@tf.function` compiled functions are virtual and have some limitations when computing with ordinary variables. It seems like `image.shape[0]//LR_SCALE` produces an error. The following code works perfectly when I resize the image into a fixed size, but how am I supposed to rescale the image with a certain factor?

```
@tf.function()
def generate_val_data(image):
  # Returns (LR, HR )
  image=tf.dtypes.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
  lr = tf.image.resize(image, (image.shape[0]//LR_SCALE, image.shape[1]//LR_SCALE) ,method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)
  return lr,image * 2 - 1

set5 = set5.map(generate_val_data)
```

Result:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-44-9f6ec7f6c92c>:13 generate_val_data  *
        lr = tf.image.resize(image, (image.shape[0]//LR_SCALE, image.shape[1]//LR_SCALE) ,method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `generate_val_data` gets a valid image as your error shows NoneType?

Comment: @M.Innat It gets None Type because the image size is different for every image.